# How to prove De Morgan’s laws without using contradictions

Tags: logic

Is it possible to prove De Morgan’s Laws without showing a contradiction otherwise.

I’m actually asking because I’m wondering if it’s possible to prove De Morgan’s law without assuming the Law of Non-Contradiction

Comment: you could write a truth table

Answer (score 3):

$(A \land B) \to ¬(¬A \lor ¬B)$ and $A \lor B \to ¬(¬A \land ¬B)$ are intuitionistically valid.

Thus, we can prove them without [Excluded Middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle) or other classically equivalent rule.

None of the converse implications is derivable in [intuitionistic
logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/). Thus, we need LEM.

---

The proof of the first one is straightforward.

Assume $¬A \lor ¬B$ and derive a contradiction under both cases. Then conclude with $\lor$-elim followed by $\lnot$-intro.

The same for the second one, assuming $¬A \land ¬B$.